# Rename by Appending a prefix to a file name

Tags: python-3.x, file-rename

I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint. I have to rename a batch of files by adding a prefix (date) to the file name, so files are organized in ordered manner in the folder: from older to newer. 
The date itself contained inside of the file. Therefore, my script has to open the file, find the date and use it as a "prefix" to add to the file name.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re 
import os 
file = open('blog_entry.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
source_code = file.read()
<...>
# convert the date:
date = datetime.strptime(date_only, "%d-%b-%Y")
new_date = date.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
```

The **new_date** variable should be used as a "prefix", so the new file name looks like *"yyyy_mm_dd blog_entry.txt"*
I cannot wrap my head around how to generate a "new name" using this prefix, so I can apply `os.rename(old_name, new_name)` command to the file. apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, using string concatenation to build the new filename you want:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re
import os

file = open('blog_entry.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
source_code = file.read()
# read the date from the file contents
date = datetime.strptime(date_only, "%d-%b-%Y")
new_date = date.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
path = "/path/to/your/file/"
os.rename(path + 'blog_entry.txt', path + new_date + ' ' + 'blog_entry.txt')
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! Quick question: can I use a variable instead of 'blog_entry.txt'. As I will be looping through the list of files, i.e. for file in files: <code here>

Comment: @user136555 Yes, you may simply replace `'blog_entry.txt'` by some string variable, and the above snippet should still work.

Comment: One more question: when I try to loop trough with the script, I get the following error: OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:

Comment: You might have to use a valid path/location for renaming, unless your Python script happen to be executing in the same folder containing the files you want to rename.